# Better way of writing the switch

Tags: javascript

Any shorter (or more efficient) way to write this . just to be precise, daily, weekly... are being fetched from the interface (input[select])

```
switch(repeatFrequency) {
                case "daily":
                    diffDays = 1;
                    break;
                case "weekly":
                    diffDays = 7;
                    break;
                case "weekly_2":
                    diffDays = 14;
                    break;
                case "monthly":
                    diffDays=31;//we assume the worst case
                    break;
                case "monthly_3":
                    diffDays = 92;//we assume the worst case
                    break;
}
```

Comment: The better way is use hash (map) object: `key => value`

Comment: Yep, this is a simple object with one-liner access (checking for validity should be included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is use hash (map) object. Something like this:

```
var hash = {
    'daily': 1,
    'weekly': 7,
    'weekly_2': 14,
    'monthly': 31,
    'monthly_3': 93,
};
var diffDays = repeatFrequency in hash? hash[repeatFrequency] : default_value;
```

Comment: You could actually just skip the check on the last line - if it doesn't find a match, it will be undefined just the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but does the operator 'in' for a hash work on all browsers ?

Comment: @Anthony N. Sure, [it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). However, it's unnecessary to do such check. You can simply assign `hash` value as is, as Katana314 suggested, unless you want to have default value for the variable.

Comment: Thanks guys :) yeh i'd rather not use the in operator because it's slow, I'll protect my code elsewhere

Comment: @AnthonyN. What? No. `in` isn't slow. When you do `thing.thing` *anywhere* in JavaScript, you are doing a string hash-map lookup. Heck, simply interacting with the browser it might be impossible to avoid doing about 20 hashmap lookups in one method. The language, and its `Object` type in general, are optimized for that kind of thing. `in` is just a different form of checking for a key.

Comment: @Katana314 I used jsPerf to test it vs indexOf (for short strings) and vs several if's and I'm not saying that it's slow in general, I'm just saying that in my case in particular it's slower than the other 3 methods. And it's cool to know how JavaScript works. Thanks !

Comment: @AnthonyN. I think it could be comparable to a `unordered_map<string>` vs `string[]` in C++; it's certainly going to be simpler to check an array for small series, but won't scale so well up to big values. So, there's maybe an imperceptible performance benefit if you know you'll have less than 50 entries, but even if I had legitimate performance concerns for the usage, that's not the sort of thing I would focus on when writing JS.